# How to propagate a server's host name on local DNS

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns, lan

I am asking this question because I don't know which network service should do this.

I have a lightweight server on my LAN, and its host name is `my_server`.

Now I would like every machine on my local area network to automatically update their DNS records to associate the IP address of my server to `my_server`.

The reason I want to do that, is because the IP address of this server is allocated by a DHCP server, and it can change.

My router has only a DHCP server and doesn't offer a DNS server. Actually it is a host-only network managed by VirtualBox, so network features are very limited.

Is there something that can propagate a host name on the LAN, just like the Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) propagates the MAC address associated with a specific IP address? Some kind of autodiscovery protocol?

Comment: There is the MDNS protocol, but support for that as a low-level system resolver is pretty limited.

Comment: Thanks @JonasWielicki! MDNS seems to be what I was looking for. After installation, my server is visible as `my_server.local`. I'm trying to remove `.local` now.

Answer (score 0):

You network sounds decentralized, so trying to update records from a central point is very difficult.

There are no "DNS" records on the clients to update, they make requests to a DNS server, and it responds with the address it currently has for `my_server`.  You need to update the DNS server they communicate with, not the clients themselves.

The best way to do this on a LAN is with a local DHCP-integrated dynamic DNS (DDNS) setup so that whenever DHCP hands out a different address to a device, it add/updates the matching record in DNS, so that all clients know where to find it.

For example, Windows Server accomplishes this by allowing its DHCP server service to update the DNS server records.

Set the clients to use the local DNS server (only), and set the local DNS server to forward unknown address requests off to external (Internet) DNS servers.

If you are going to depend on DNS lookups but don't have an internal DNS server, then you're going to have to look at updating the HOSTS files on each computer on the LAN each time the IP address of the server changes.  This could probably be scripted in some situation, but your router sounds limited so I highly doubt it be able to run a (possibly remote) script each time it hands out a DHCP lease.

Comment: I don't have control over the DHCP server and don't have a local DNS server, so my choice was MDNS… and it worked well for me! And it is as simple as typing `apt-get install avahi-daemon` on Ubuntu.